# Permission declared in instrumental test manifest can't be granted

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, permissions, manifest

I'm automating UI in android and have faced the next problem:
I have Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="ru.me.widgets"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    ...

</manifest>
```

And Android Test Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="ru.me.widgets.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have saveScreenshot method that uses external memory:

```
protected final void saveScreenshot() {

    Bitmap bitmap = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().takeScreenshot();

    File screenshotFile = getScreenshotFile();

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(screenshotFile)) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        Log.i(mTag, "Saved screenshot: " + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(mTag, "Could not save screenshot", e);
    }
}

private File getScreenshotFile() {

    String path = isExternalWritable(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext())
            ? Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            : Environment.getDataDirectory().toString();

    Date thisMoment = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    String filename = "screen-" + mTag + "-" + sdf.format(thisMoment) + SCREENSHOT_EXTENSION;

    return new File(path + "/" + filename);
}

private boolean isExternalWritable(Context context) {

    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        Log.i(mTag, "No rights for writing to external storage!");
        return false;
    }

    else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        Log.i(mTag, "External storage is in ONLY_READ mode!");
        return false;
    }

    Log.i(mTag, "External storage is not mounted!");
    return false;
}
```

After installing application I run UI-tests and I can find extra application for tests in device settings. I grant permissions for EXTERNAL_WRITE, but still get error:

```
06-18 12:22:19.998 5566-5582/ru.me.widgets I/DemoActivityTest: No rights for writing to external storage!
06-18 12:22:20.001 5566-5582/ru.me.widgets E/DemoActivityTest: Could not save screenshot
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/screen-DemoActivityTest-2018-06-18_12:22:19.png (Permission denied)
```

How can I save screenshot in my UI-tests? Why after granting permission for external write in settings "Permission denied" error occures?
If I set sharedUserId in manifest, all works, but I think that this is a wrong way of solving problem.

Also, in future, I will need to grant permissions automatically, using GrandPermissionRule. But it works only if I set permission in App Manifest, not in Android Test Manifest.

Comment: Problem solved by using applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES) that doesn't require any permissions.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6.0 or higher, you must add request permission base on code into this Activity instead of just only grant permission in Manifest.

References for you, hope it will help you:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting